# how to send a byte array through udp using ansi c?

Tags: c

i want to send a byte array on udp through an ansi c program how can we use this.

Comment: open socket. write to socket. close socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Socket tutorial](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Err, ANSI/ISO C doesn't include sockets.